# Power Cycling USB

Tags: microcontroller, power, mosfet, usb, data

BACKGROUND
I am connecting a USB device to a PCB with a microcontroller. The USB must be power cycled (plugged out and in) in order for the USB to be recognised by the software. The USB connector will be inaccessible to the user in the final design so I have decided to power cycle the USB using an N channel MOSFET (2N7007). So when the software loads it will send a signal to the gate of the MOSFET to toggle it off and on.

ISSUE
The USB is reading OK when the USB GND is connected straight to PCB GND. When the MOSFET was introduced the USB was no longer reading. I can see the software is definitely toggling the gate on. With the USB disconnected I can see continuity from the drain to the GND on the PCB. When I connect the USB I no longer get continuity from  the drain to GND on the PCB.
The USB device is functioning ok (no shorts) when connected straight to GND but for some reason it doesn't function when going through the MOSFET[image]

SETUP

- PSU 5V and GND connected to main PCB
- USB 5V connected to 5V supply from PCB
- USB D+ and D- connected to PCB going to micro
- USB GND connected to MOSFET drain, PCB GND connected to source and 3.3V software control signal connected to gate
  [image]

Comment: Uhm... What is the voltage of those D+/D- lines when not powered? I'm pretty convinced that those lines go to GND, so the MOSFET is not actually removing power (USB device is wrongly powered through +5V And D+/D-). Try to measure the voltage at D+ and D- when no USB device is connected, and then try using a P-MOS to cut the +5V (I think that is how it is done in "switched" USB HUBs)

Comment: Considerably,  MCU powered from another source, not from USB. Make sure that source's ground and USB ground are  connected. If not, it needs galvanic isolated switch.

Comment: Is there a special reason not to switch off the +5 V line? As I understand, the PCB is an USB host. It should be possible to restart the device enumeration and drivers via software. Do you need a kind of power on reset in the USB device?

Answer (score 2):

You show a 3.3 Volt logic signal driving the [2N7000](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/2N7000-N-Channel-Enhancement-Mode-Vertical-DMOS-FET-Data-Sheet-20005695A.pdf).  Looking at that datasheet, several of the device parameters are important:

- `Static Drain-to-Source On-State Resistance` \$\text{RDS}_{\text{(ON)}}\$ = 5Ω -- When fully "on", this (source-to-drain path) will be like a 5Ω resistor *at best*.  For very light loads this might be ok, but this could be causing problems.  Measure voltage across source-drain when attempting to operate, and use that voltage to calculate what resistance it is.  Bet you find it is more like 30 Ohms, which is one aspect of why this isn't working.
- `Gate Threshold Voltage` \$\text{VGS}_{\text{(th)}}\$ = 3 V for \$\text{I}_{\text{D}}\$ = 1 mA -- This means that for a gate-source voltage at 3.0 Volts, 0.001 Ampere is guaranteed through source-drain.  At 3.30V, that may be slightly higher, perhaps 25mA but this datasheet doesn't say explicitly.  Bottom line is, for this device, to get the actual 5Ω impedance, a gate voltage of 5 V or so will be needed.

The 2N7000 can be used to switch light loads, but this device is actually more suited to amplifier and high-speed roles as it has very little gate capacitance (60pF = 0.000060µF.)  This feature also makes it incredibly sensitive to electro-static discharge. Out of all of the "ESD-sensitive" parts commonly encountered, the 2N7000 is one of the most sensitive to it.  Bottom line is, they can be damaged just from handling and soldering without ESD precautions. So the device could have already been invisibly damaged.

But really, an N-channel Enhancement-Mode MOSFET in the ground path is not the best choice for switching a USB device on and off.  This is because when "off", the positive and D+/D- are still connected to the device.  When D+/D- are low, *that* will try to be "ground" and some current will still flow from positive into the device.  The host will likely get confused and turn off the port from it's end.

A better solution is a P-channel Enhancement-Mode MOSFET in the positive path.  Such is called a "high-side switch" because you want to cut the supply ("high-side", +5V) to the device altogether.  There are many questions here about high-side switches, so search for that for more info.

In summary, replace the 2N7000 with a P-channel version in the +5V line. Use a 100k resistor from +5V to its gate, which normally keeps it "off."  And pull that gate to 0V to turn it "on" and allow 5 V to the USB device.

The astute will ask "what about D+/D-; can't they leak power to the USB device when +5V is disconnected? And is that even safe?"  The answer is, possibly. In an ideal world, all four of the connections should be interrupted in unison.  But due to the speed of USB, this makes "easy" solutions like a four-pole relay problematic. (D+/D- are a precisely-matched pair of signals; the variability of relay contact resistance can interfere with that, especially on newer/faster USB.)  It also means that interfacing other discrete components into the D+/D- lines (such as a "level translator" or "bipolar switch") are too slow and would also affect operation.  So just cutting the +5V is the lesser-of-two-evils: it should work (and is not a good solution) but is better than cutting the ground.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot toggle GND for USB. If ground is disconnected, voltage form VBUS leaks out via the data wires, making the computer think a device is being plugged in. Since the computer cannot talk to the device in this state, it will stop communications after 3 times. Even after you enable the mosfet after this moment, the port stays disabled.

You need to use a p-channel mosfet to toggle VBUS instead

Answer (score -1):

If you want to brute force, you can wire a GPIO to reset pin and pull the microcontroller to reset. Once it restarts the GPIO will be in high impedance mode and allow the microcontroller to boot.

The microcontroller datasheet might reveal more elegant solutions for reset or re-enabling just the USB HW.